# after reset-prompt,the command line jump to next line automatically

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc, zsh-completion, zsh-zle

---

①I have tried to use an dynamic clock with `time refresh` settings in `~/.zshrc`

```
TMOUT=1
TRAPALRM () 
{ zle reset-prompt }
```

②my full modified theme file is [bullet-train.zsh-theme](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BpYPJtW2wg/)
my whole `~/.zshrc` file is[.zshrc](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/nzHtZY2Rd8/)

---

**My problem is:
when my terminal enter into a git repository,**

**the command line will jump to the next line automatically.**

the `jump behavior` is  like this:
[image]

when I change the name of .git to .git__xx folder.
then `jump behavior`stop

I swear that I did not press `Enter`,
the terminal jump to the next line automatically.
I guess it's caused by Anaconda and the `time refresh` settings in `~/.zshrc`

**The phenomenon is recorded in [here](https://asciinema.org/a/DOq78og1q0ZCdZW0c6RlOEDDe)**

---

Did I press `Enter` deliberately and post this question to waste others' time?

No,here's the effect
if I press `Enter`to make command line jump to the next line

[image]

---

some unproper solution:

delete git part in theme file `bullet-train.zsh-theme`.

Then the phenomenon disappear,but the `git display` function is also disabled.

---

Could you tell me how to solve this bug?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure `zsh` supports rewriting an existing prompt in the way you want. What do you mean by "time flush" settings?

Comment: Thanks for your replies,it's my bad,I misremember that word, and I post a new link about this phenomenon.Thanks for your help.